# Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'T' (from class template) in List

Tags: c#, c++, generics

I am doing converting code to C# from C++ but having some problem for the vector part for generics variable issue.I am beginner in C#.

C++ code:

```
  Pvec(){}
  Pvec(size_t n): p(n) {}
  Pvec(size_t n, T v): p(n, v) {}

  template<class T2>
  Pvec(const vector<T2>& v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); ++i)
      p[i] = v[i];
  }

  template<class T2>
  Pvec(const Pvec<T2>& v) {
    p.resize(v.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
      p[i] = v[i];
  }
```

C# code (converting by me but  facing a lot of **error**):

```
public class Pvec <T>
{
  private List<T> p = new List<T>();

  public Pvec()
  {
  }
  public Pvec(uint n)
  {
      this.p = n;
  }
  public Pvec(uint n, T v)
  {
      this.p = new List<T>(n, v);
  }

//ORIGINAL LINE: template<class T2>
  public Pvec<T2>(List<T2> v)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < p.Count; ++i)
    {
      p[i] = v[i];
    }
  }

//ORIGINAL LINE: template<class T2>
  public Pvec<T2>(Pvec<T2> v)
  {
    p.resize(v.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
      p[i] = v[i];
    }
  }
```

How about i have more than two template in class?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: It's so strang, that Pvec constructor takes parameter `T v` instead of `const T & v`.

Comment: this.p.Add(n);
-cannot convert from 'unit' to 'T"

this.p = n;
-cannot implicitly convert type 'unit' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'

this.p = new List<T>(n, v);
-initializes a new instance of the List<T> class that is empty and has the default initial capacity

@YuvalItzchakov

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code. First of all, you're trying to assign a `uint` to a `List<T>`, where no such conversion exists. Furthermore, you're trying to set `List<T>` with a constructor taking a count which is of type `int` and not `uint`. What you need to do:

1. Use `this.p = new List<T>()` which uses the `List<T>` constructor
2. Either accept an `int`, or cast the `uint` to an `int`.
3. I would leave the declaration of `p` uninstantiated, as you initialize it in the constructor anyway.
4. Use constructor chaining

   ```
   public class Pvec<T>
   {
       private List<T> p;
       private const int DefaultVectorSize = 4;

       public Pvec() : this(DefaultVectorSize, default(T))
       {
       }
       public Pvec(uint n) : this((int)n, default(T))
       {
       }
       public Pvec(uint n, T v)
       {
          var capacity = (int)n;
          p = EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(v, default(T)) ? 
                               new List<T>(capacity) { v } : new List<T>(capacity);
       }
   }
   ```

Or:

```
public class Pvec<T>
{
    private List<T> p;
    private const int DefaultVectorSize = 4;

    public Pvec() : this(DefaultVectorSize, default(T))
    {
    }
    public Pvec(int n) : this(n, default(T))
    {
    }
    public Pvec(int n, T v)
    {
        p =  EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(v, default(T)) ? 
                                new List<T>(n) { v } : new List<T>(n);
    }
}
```

Side note - Give you parameters meaningful names.

Comment: hmm i got a question,it is possible don't put any vector size just let it based on the how big of the input value max size can assign to the variable ?

Comment: I didn't understand your question

Comment: it is ok.can you look back my question.I added few line code.how about i make more than one template class .It is possible ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `PVec<T>` is usable for any `T`. Why another template?

Comment: because later on i will use it for this 
  template<class T2>
  Pvec<T>& operator=(const vector<T2>& v) {
 .......
  }
actually i am doing the conversion of C++ to C#,the code is doing for positive vector.This is one of my education project

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
public Pvec(uint n)
{
    this.p = n;
}
```

You are trying to assign a `uint` to a list.  In the C++ code the `uint` is the size of the `vector`.  You need to mirror this in C#.  You could do it this way:

```
public Pvec(int n)
{
    p = new List<T>(n);
}
```

Note - I changed from `uint` to `int` since this is the type for the list constructor.  You could leave it as a `uint` and handle the conversion in the constructor but with the warning that you could pass in a value that would overflow.

Comment: how about i already declare outside the methods so i still need to re-declare the new List<T>(n) like this ?sorry that i just was a beginner

Comment: @ChuenZN - instead of declaring `new List<T>` where you define the member variable, you should just initialize it in the constructor. You should look at Yuval's answer and use constructor chaining to make the code more maintainable.